# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Too many open files)

Tags: java, file-io

I use the following code to write some data to files:

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    writer.write(...);
    writer.flush();
}
finally {
    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();
}
```

After invoking the method multiple times I got a FileNotFoundException because too many files are open.

Obviously java does not close the file handles when I close the writer stream. Closing the FileWriter separately does not help.

Is there sth. I can do to force java to close the files?

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace? Are you using this perhaps in a multi threaded environment?

Comment: Try adding `try .. catch around `writer.close()` too, to catch any problems there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. It could be another part of your application which is leaking file handles.

You can monitor file handles using `lsof` on Linux or `pfiles` on Solaris. On Windows, you can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: You're right. The problem does not occur, if I run just the code I posted. Though it threw the exception because there were just no more files left to open. Seems I have to find the leak somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

No, Java does close the file handles when you close the writer. Its actually built using [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Hence, it must be something else. Show the stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace points only to the code, I posted. But you're right the problems is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069698/when-to-use-which-writer-subclass-in-java-common-practices) about writing to files, good tips there.. pay attention to the finally block in Anons reply.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedWriter closes the underlying stream. Probably, this a multithreading issue. You can keep an instance of FileOutputStream and close it. Something like:

```
java.io.FileOutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
try {
  // make buffered writer, etc.
} finally {
  out.close();
}
```